# Trouble sending redirect after logout

Tags: 8, hooks, redirection

I'm trying to send a redirect after logout, but it is not sending properly. I tried using the *hook_user_logout* in a module as follows:

```
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;

function module_user_logout($account) {
  $redirect = new TrustedRedirectResponse($url);
  $redirect->send();
}
```

The send() call causes the page to crash with the message: "The __ page isn't working"

Comment: maybe because the $url is empty ? Or maybe because you need to add return at the end of the function. Cheers

Comment: To add what @DenisK said, `hook_user_logout()` implementations aren't supposed to redirect users. That would not allow other `hook_user_logout()` implementations to be invoked.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve current issue we need to create RouteSubscriber
my_custom/src/EventSubscriber/MyCustomRouteSubscriber.php :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_custom\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RoutingEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

    /**
     * MyCustom Route subscriber.
     */
    class MyCustomRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        $events = parent::getSubscribedEvents();
        $events[RoutingEvents::ALTER] = ['onAlterRoutes', -300];
        return $events;
      }

      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
        if ($route = $collection->get('user.logout')) {
          $route->setDefaults([
            '_controller' => '\Drupal\my_custom\Controller\MyCustomUserLogoutController::logout',
          ]);
        }
      }

    }
```

Then add entry into my_custom.services.yml:

```
  my_custom.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\my_custom\EventSubscriber\MyCustomRouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Then create actual controller which will replace users module logout method.
my_custom/src/Controller/MyCustomUserLogoutController.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_custom\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;

/**
 * Class MyCustomUserLogoutController.
 */
class MyCustomUserLogoutController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Logs the current user out.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
   *   A redirection to home page.
   */
  public function logout() {
    user_logout();
    $logout_url = 'https://google.com'
    return new TrustedRedirectResponse($logout_url);
  }

}
```

Hope it will save your time.

Thanks